# OAuth 2.0 vs Auth0

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0

What is the difference between OAuth 2.0 and Auth0? Which one should I use to develop the authentication system?

Answer (score 196):

[OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) is a standardized authorization protocol, [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) is a company that sells an identity management platform with authentication and authorization services that *implements* the OAuth2 protocol (among others).

Answer (score 91):

**[OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/)** is a protocol that allows a user to grant limited access to their resources on one site, to another site, without having to expose their credentials.

**[Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/getting-started/overview)** is an organisation, who manages Universal Identity Platform for web, mobile and IoT can handle any of them — B2C, B2B, B2E, or a combination.

**Note**: Okta, Inc, on May 3, 2021 announced the successful completion of its acquisition of Auth0.

[Source](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols)

Answer (score 37):

In case if you cannot understand any of above,

- **OAuth 2** - is a standard or protocol to implement authorization for any kind of software (windows, mobile or web)
- **Auth0** - is a software product (cloud and on-prem), that implements the OAuth2 protocol. You can use Auth0 to simplify your
  authentication and authorization requirements.

Answer (score 4):

We mainly use auth 2.0 for session based security management at server side. OAuth 2.0 is an authorisation framework that enables a third-party application to obtain limited access to resources the end-user owns. It is about resource access and sharing. While https://auth0.com is a company that sells an identity management platform for authentication  related task. So with the help of auth0.com services an app developer don't need to write code for login/registration/social login and its not needed to think about its security. Complete user management task manages by auth0 organisation.

Answer (score 2):

What Identity Provider are you aiming to use?

Auth0, identityserver, ADFS 4.0 etc. all support the OAuth stack.

Using implicit OAuth flow you can connect your Angular application to any of these.